# Java read a w3c.Document from different thread

Tags: java, xml, multithreading

I'm trying to read an XML document with multiple threads.  The documents are very large!  The program works if I use a sinlge thread but if I use a worker thread I get errors.
As a single thread it takes about 30-40 seconds to load.  As multiple threads it takes about 5 seconds.  So the advantage is clear.  However I just can't get it to work.
If anyone can shed some light on this I'd love to know.

Here is some code.  Not exactly what I have (removed a lot of comments and try-catch blocks and stuff that doesn't relate to the problem)

```
        import org.w3c.dom.*;
        import java.net.URL;
        private static DocumentBuilder getBuilder() {
          try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            return dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            String err = "error initializing API interface: \n" + ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(err);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err, "Loading error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
          }
          return null;
        }
        public void loadPage(String page) {
          URL url = new URL(page);
          Document doc = getBuilder().parse(url.openStream());
          Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
          NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
          for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nodes.item(i);
            if (n instanceof Element) {
              // move node to new document.
              Document doc;
              doc = getBuilder().newDocument();
              Node nn = doc.adoptNode(n);
              doc.appendChild(nn);
              Element ele = (Element)nn;
              new Parser(ele).start(); // Causes errors...
              //new Parser(ele).run(); // Works, but isn't threaded.
              NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
              i = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        public class Parser implements Runnable {
          private Element ele;
          public Parser(Element e) {
            ele = e;
          }
          public void start() {
            new Thread(this).start();
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // Parse the document here.
            // I get errors here if it's multi-threaded.
          }
        }
```

Edit:

The errors are corrupted data.  Upon further testing I've discovered the problem is even worse than I thought.  The function 'loadPage' above is called from a thread.  My testing at the point I posted this question was done with only one thread running.  However I have found that if I run multiple page loads in parrelell (even thought they are completely different pages) I get errors even if I'm only using one thread per page...

My fear it that there is a static object being used somewhere that is causing a state corruption and resulting in my corrupted data.

An example of the corrupted data is like this.

```
     // when reading the XML
     // <Date>2015-6-1</Date>
      public String getText(Element ele) {
        String val = ele.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
      }
     // I will get either an empty string or somthing like "13E13" or ".5D4"
```

And by multiple page loads I mean the following:

```
        public void loadAll(List<String> pages) {
          for(String page : pages) {
            new Loader(page).start();
          }
        }
        public class Loader implements Runnable {
          private String page;
          public Loader(String p) {
            page = p;
          }
          public void start() {
            new Thread(this).start();
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
            loadPage(page);
          }
        }
```

Comment: What do your errors look like? Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: If you don't tell us what the errors are, we can't help you.

Comment: Found the probelm, deep in my code I had a static DateFormat object that I was using.  I though the data was corrupted because of the value that was reported in the error string.

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208584/parallel-xml-parsing-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is not thread-safe. All access needs to be synchronized, even read-only access. That's because the DOM does lazy evaluation, so apparent read requests can trigger internal updates. It's all pretty horrible. You would be much better off using XOM or JDOM2 if that's possible.

Comment: I found the problem. It wasn't with the XML parsing, I had that sufficently seperated into individual documents.  The problem was burried deep in my code was a parser that was declared static and got shared between all threads.  That's what was corrupting my data.